# NSTimer on UIToolbar

Tags: xcode, nstimer, uitoolbar

In my project I am implementing NSTimer to calculate time.
What I want to do is,

I am having my UIToolBar in my Timer.m file with tag 100.
and I want to add NSTimer on my UIToolBar from TimerController.m

But I am not able to add NStimer on UIToolBar.
My Timer is getting added over my navigation bar.

How to add my Timer on UIToolbar.
Can any one guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code...

Timer.m

```
UIToolbar* bottomToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
bottomToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 390, self.frame.size.width, 44);
[bottomToolbar sizeToFit];
bottomToolbar.tintColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
bottomToolbar.tag = 100;
[self addSubview:bottomToolbar];
```

and this is my time in TimerController.h

```
    NSTimer* timer;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer* timer;
```

and code for this timer in TimerController.m

```
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(displayTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and in `displayTime` method I will go for timing calculation.

I didn't found ant property to add timer over UIToolBar.

I tried using below code, but it give me warning with no output.
Warning as "incompatible pointer types sending NStimer* to prameter of UIView*"

```
UIToolbar *bottomBar = (UIToolbar*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
[bottomBar addSubview:timer];
```

Here is the image how I want it....

@note :- I also checked whether my Toolbar tag is getting problem, but NO,
I am able to add UIToolbar and `nslog` tag correctly.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: why don't you just make `UIToolbar* bottomToolbar` a property and use it instead of using tags

Comment: Actually, I need to other stuff too on UIToolBar, like label, button and images along with timer.
so all those stuff in controller cause mess in code and may RUN time crash. so using UIToolBar in View and action in controller

Comment: I think you need to research more into the code and go through some guides. For starters an NSTimer cannot be added to a view hierarchy. Possibly you have overlapping names. An NSTimer is an object that calls a function every x seconds. It won't display anything though. You would use a UILabel for that

Comment: Ok,
Will go for it
thanks